# Simple code works in immediate window, generates 1004 error in application

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code in my application that generates a 1004 error :

```
range(cells(1, 103), cells(157, 112)).select
```

However, if I copy this code into the immediate window and execute it I can see the cells getting selected.

If I use `Range("CY1", "DH157").Select`
 the application run OK with no error.

What on earth is going on here ?

Thanks you !

Update:
I have created a simple two sheet file with the following code in "scratch":

```
Private Sub testcode_Click()

    Sheets("scratch").Activate
    Range(Cells(5, 5), Cells(10, 10)).Select

    Sheets("testtab").Activate
    Sheets("testtab").Range("A1:E5").Select
    Sheets("testtab").Range("B10:C16").Select
    Sheets("testtab").Range(Cells(5, 5), Cells(10, 10)).Select

End Sub
```

The code will execute correctly UNTIL the last statement is executed. This produces the '1004' error, at least on my system

I found a similar question from 2015 that Rory answered and it works correctly for me now. Apparently the Cells calls are referring to the sheet the code resides on even though the alternative sheet is activated. The following works correctly:

Sheets("testtab").Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 5), _ 
            ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 10)).Select

Mystery solved! Thank you Rory!
Thanks everyone.

Comment: This is not reproducible.  `Range(cells(1, 103), cells(157, 112)).select`  _does_ work as a sub

Comment: I tried this approach in a separate application and it worked fine there. But in the original application, it has this very bizarre behavior. Is there some option or environment variable that could cause this? You can tell I'm grasping at straws on this.

Comment: Needs more context...

Comment: Can we have entire code because both of .select are working.
Also, some users have this kind of error when our code are pushed on a  sheet module. Try to create a new module (insert -> module) and past your code.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of behavior is easy to reproduce
Put the follwoing code into the sheet module of sheet1

```
Sub Test()
 Range(Cells(1, 103), Cells(157, 112)).Select
End Sub
```

Add a second sheet, activate it and run the sub Test from the sheet module of sheet1. The issue is that you try to select a range on sheet1 which is not active at that time.